# Git: fatal: unable to find remote helper for 'ssl'

Tags: windows, git, bash, ssl, github

I have some trouble with git. I´m new at working with them. 
I use Git 1.9.4-preview20140929_win on Windows 8.1, for SSL verification I use Putty.
Connect with server by SSL is ok, I have respons from server that key is ok. 
If I try to clone in Git Bash with

```
$ git clone ssl://git@[server_name]:/home/test.git
```

I get this:
Cloning into 'test.git' ...
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'ssl'

Other clone commands works ok (like $ git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git.

Thanks a lot for any answer

Comment: Try git clone ssh://git@...